# Where does the query table "taxonomy_term_data_node" come from?

Tags: views, database

I'm troubleshooting a Views' query which uses `taxonomy_term_data_node.weight`, but  there is no table of this name. Actually, the table name is taxonomy_term_data as you well know. So how is this table reference made? I do not see that alias in the query.

```sql
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, 
  taxonomy_term_data_node_1.weight AS taxonomy_term_data_node_1_weight, 
  taxonomy_term_data_node.weight AS taxonomy_term_data_node_weight, 
  'node' AS field_data_field_category_child_node_entity_type, 
  'node' AS field_data_field_category_parent_node_entity_type
FROM {node} node

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid
    FROM {taxonomy_term_data} td                                
    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} tv ON td.vid = tv.vid
    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} tn ON tn.tid = td.tid                
    WHERE  (tv.machine_name IN ('category_child')
  ) 
) taxonomy_term_data_node ON node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node.nid

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid
  FROM {taxonomy_term_data} td
  INNER JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} tv ON td.vid = tv.vid
  INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} tn ON tn.tid = td.tid
  WHERE (tv.machine_name IN  ('category_parent')) 
) taxonomy_term_data_node_1 ON node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node_1.nid

WHERE (((node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN ('group_by_test'))))
ORDER BY taxonomy_term_data_node_1_weight ASC, taxonomy_term_data_node_weight ASC
LIMIT 1000 
OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid
    FROM {taxonomy_term_data} td                                
    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} tv ON td.vid = tv.vid
    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} tn ON tn.tid = td.tid                
    WHERE  (tv.machine_name IN ('category_child')
  ) 
) taxonomy_term_data_node ON node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node.nid
```

Is the same as this.

```sql
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    td.*,
    tn.nid AS nid
  FROM {taxonomy_term_data} AS td
  LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} AS tv ON td.vid = tv.vid
  LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} AS tn ON tn.tid = td.tid
  WHERE (tv.machine_name IN ('category_child'))
) AS taxonomy_term_data_node ON node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node.nid
```

The AS Alias has been omitted on the join statements in the example query.

Comment: +1. for answering the core of the question by providing the full syntax.

Answer (score 3):

taxonomy_term_data_node is the alias used for the `SELECT` that is part of the first `LEFT JOIN`.

```sql
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid
    FROM {taxonomy_term_data} td                                
    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} tv ON td.vid = tv.vid
    LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} tn ON tn.tid = td.tid                
    WHERE  (tv.machine_name IN ('category_child')
  ) 
) taxonomy_term_data_node ON node.nid = taxonomy_term_data_node.nid
```

Comment: I can't accept a tautological answer.

Comment: i guess there is the reason why your acceptance rate is 53%

Comment: @Austin you're welcome to _try_ to add useful answers to any of my questions (^_^)

Comment: @xtian Your question was not how to rewrite the SQL query; it was, "how is this table reference made?" to which I answered.

Comment: We continually disagree about my questions and your answers Kiamlaluno. I really don't know how to respond to you anymore. All I can say is read the accepted answer.

Comment: @xtian I read it, and the difference is just between "taxonomy_term_data_node is the alias used for the `SELECT`," and "the AS Alias has been omitted on the join statements"; in other words, both the answers are saying that is an alias for the `SELECT` statement. I don't remember discussing with you about your questions, though.